# Why is a button contained in an asp.net repeater control embedded in an ASCX user control throwing an exception when clicked?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, ascx

I'm building an asp.net application with VB.Net on the code behind.

I have an asp::repeater which is contained in a user control (ASCX) which is contained in a page (aspx). The repeater contains a button. When I click on the button, that's when the validation error gets thrown.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164104.aspx

I have downloaded the C# version and it works as advertised.

For the purposes of the client's requirements, we are attempting to rewrite the control in VB.Net.
 The tab in this example is wrapped in an asp:Repeater control.
 We have run into an issue where the OnItemCommand handler (on the server side) does not get fired.
 Clicking on the button (tab) does however generate a postback.

Here is the basic HTML of the pages/user controls:

**Test page**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"
    CodeBehind="test3m.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestTabbedGridView.test3m" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/DataSetGrid.ascx" TagName="DataSetGrid" TagPrefix="ucDataSetGrid" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <ucDataSetGrid:DataSetGrid runat="server" width="600px" height="310px" ID="dataGrid" />
</asp:Content>
```

**DataSetGrid User Control:**

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" CodeBehind="DataSetGrid.ascx.vb"
    Inherits="TestTabbedGridView.DataSetGrid" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/TabStrip.ascx" TagName="TabStrip" TagPrefix="ucTabStrip" %>
<table id="__theTable" runat="server" bgcolor="ivory" border="1" cellpadding="0"
    cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <ucTabStrip:TabStrip ID="ts" runat="server" SelectedBackColor="Cyan" OnSelectionChanged="SelectionChanged" />
            <asp:DataGrid ID="__theGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="0"
                Font-Name="verdana" Font-Size="8pt" GridLines="none" OnItemCommand="ItemCommand"
                OnPageIndexChanged="PageIndexChanged" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedIndexChanged"
                PageSize="12" Width="100%">
                <PagerStyle font-name="webdings" Font-Size="150%" NextPageText="4" Position="top"
                    PrevPageText="3" />
                <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="yellow" />
                <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="ivory" />
                <ItemStyle BackColor="#eeeeee" />
            </asp:DataGrid>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**TabStrip User Control:**

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" CodeBehind="TabStrip.ascx.vb" Inherits="TestTabbedGridView.TabStrip" %>
<div class="lightbluebackground">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemCommand="ItemCommandFired">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td>
                <asp:Button CausesValidation="false" runat="server" ID="btnTab" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>"
                    CommandName="CmdSelectTab"
                    BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="solid" />
            </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Are there differences between Asp.Net C# and VB.Net which I need to be aware of?
 Is this somehow involve the ViewState?

Can someone help get me pointed in the right direction or provide clues to help track why those events are not getting fired?

Thanks,
 JohnB

Comment: How are you invoking the [button's click event](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6130834/304683)?

Comment: EdSF::> The vent is getting fired via the ItemCommand on the repeater control.